# How can i output the multi-dimenstional array to console using for-each loop?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

For example, I have the array

```
int [] array = new int[2];
```

using code

```
for (int i: array){
    System.out.println(i);
};
```

I see the output 0 and 0, it's expected

but what if I want to output the multi-array:

```
int [][] array2 = new int[2]\[2];
```

```
for (int[] i : array2) {
    for(int[] j : array2 ){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
};
```

I have strange output

```
[[I@7d4991ad, [I@28d93b30]
[[I@7d4991ad, [I@28d93b30]
[[I@7d4991ad, [I@28d93b30]
[[I@7d4991ad, [I@28d93b30]
[[I@7d4991ad, [I@28d93b30]
[[I@7d4991ad, [I@28d93b30]
```

but expected result for me is

```
0 0
0 0
```

Comment: what do you think those for loops are doing?

Comment: Did you consider [`Arrays.deepToString(j)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D))?

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of arrays, so each index in `array2` contains another array that is an object itself. What you get back your way is the memory address of this object.

An easy way to print the array the way you want it would be the following:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; i < array.length; j++){
        System.out.println(array[i][j]);
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks, but i know this way, so I want to know how using this type of loop, that I asked

Comment: for (int[] i: array2){
            for (int j: i){
                System.out.println(j);
            }
        }

that's what I want to know

Answer (score 2):

This should help to print

```
for (int[] row : array2) {
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
```

Output

```
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

The OP, Conspicuous, reported in a comment:

```
int[][] array2 = new int[2][2];
for (int[] i : array2) {
    for (int j : i) {
        System.out.printf("%-2d", j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

That's what I want to know.

Output:

```
0 0 
0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to use the length property of the array and an indexed var vs a foreach approach.

https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/multidimensional-arrays-in-java/

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. I am unsure what you are trying to tell us, though. By *vs*, did you mean either one or the other? The OP is already using a foreach loop (even two of them). The answer by Mahesh Biradar uses one and works fine. I am curious what you meant to suggest that would solve the OP’s problem?